# Matlab: Use cross-entropy in neural network

Tags: matlab, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to implement a RNN using cross-entropy. The following is my code:

```
net = layrecnet(1:2,10);
net.performFcn = 'crossentropy';
net.performParam.regularization = 0.1;
net.performParam.normalization = 'none';
[Xs,Xi,Ai,Ts] = preparets(net, featureMatrix, labels);
net = train(net,Xs,Ts,Xi,Ai);
% view(net)
Y = net(Xs,Xi,Ai);
perf = perform(net,Y,Ts);
```

The `performParam` is from Matlab's official [doc](http://au.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/crossentropy.html). However, after I executed it, I got a warning said:

```
Warning: Performance function replaced with squared
error performance. 
> In trainlm>formatNet (line 155)
  In trainlm (line 65)
  In nntraining.setup (line 14)
  In network/train (line 335)
```

Even if I execute the feedforwardnet, I got the same warning. The following is my code.

```
[x,t] = simplefit_dataset;
net = feedforwardnet(10);
net.performFcn = 'crossentropy';
net.performParam.regularization = 0.1;
net.performParam.normalization = 'none';
net = train(net,x,t);
view(net)
y = net(x);
perf = perform(net,y,t);
```

So how could I use cross-entropy in my code?

Comment: [Check this link](http://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/261735-i-get-a-performance-function-replaced-with-squared-error-performance-warning-when-trying-to-set-c)

Comment: @obchardon I've read that before but doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `trainlm` only applies to loss functions using `Jacobian Matrix` as stated in document:

> This function uses the Jacobian for calculations, which assumes that
>   performance is a mean or sum of squared errors. Therefore, networks
>   trained with this function must use either the mse or sse performance
>   function.

One solution is using other training algos like `trainrp` or `trainscg`. The following works:

```
[x,t] = simplefit_dataset;
net = feedforwardnet(10);
net.performFcn = 'crossentropy';
net.performParam.regularization = 0.1;
net.performParam.normalization = 'none';
net.trainFcn = 'trainrp';
net = train(net,x,t);
view(net)
y = net(x);
perf = perform(net,y,t);
```